# WCF http & https endpoint one contract

Tags: .net, wcf, http, iis, https

I've created wcf service and want use http and https version. Service is hosted by IIS 6.0.

At my config I have:

```
  <bindings>
  <basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="BindingConfiguration1" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
      <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647"
      maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647"/>
      <security mode="TransportWithMessageCredential">
        <transport clientCredentialType="None"/>
        <message clientCredentialType="UserName" />
      </security>
    </binding>
  </basicHttpBinding>
</bindings> 
 <services>
  <service name="RegistratorService.Registrator" behaviorConfiguration="RegistratorService.Service1Behavior">
    <endpoint binding="basicHttpBinding"
              contract="RegistratorService.IRegistrator"
              bindingConfiguration="BindingConfiguration1">
      <identity>
        <dns value="localhost" />
      </identity>
    </endpoint>
    <endpoint binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="RegistratorService.IRegistrator">
      <identity>
        <dns value="localhost" />
      </identity>
    </endpoint>
    <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpsBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
    <host>
      <baseAddresses>
        <add baseAddress="http://aurit-server2" />
      </baseAddresses>
    </host>
  </service>
</services>
```

But even at browser I've got exception "The provided URI scheme 'http' is invalid; expected 'https'"

What's wrong? 
Thanks.

Comment: Just a guess, but you specified `TransportWithMessageCredential`. It would be hard to do that over http.

Comment: So i want realize this biding over https

Answer (score 1):

do you have SSL set up in IIS6 for the website hosting WCF. If you do make sure you don't have SSL required checked if you want to allow both http and https